# Unable to run my configuration file in jbehave

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, bdd, jbehave

I have written a simple code in java which will open the chrome browser and verify its title. Here I have used Jbehave(BDD) concept to achieve it.

The problem which I'm facing is that I'm not able to run my config file.

This is my .story file

```
narrative:
In order to communicate effectively to the business some functionality
As a development team
I want to use Behaviour-Driven Development

Scenario:  A Scenario to open google.com
Given I open a browser
When I enter the https://www.google.com
Then google is displayed
```

This is my java code for the storyline

```
     import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
    import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
    import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class DebugPluginSteps {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    @Given("I open a browser")
    public void openTheBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @When("I enter $url")
    public void typeTheUrl(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Then("$title is displayed")
    public void debugStepForThenTest(String title) {
        if (driver.getTitle() == title) {
            System.out.println("Title matched");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Title is not matching");
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is my config file.

```
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;
public class MyLinkedListStory extends JUnitStory {
    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new DebugPluginSteps());
    }
}
```

Console output :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 29264
Only local connections are allowed.
[1578918833.831][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Jan 13, 2020 6:03:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Processing system properties {}
Using controls EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=false,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeouts=300,threads=1,failOnStoryTimeout=false]
Generating reports view to 'C:\Users\Desktop\Selenium 201\SimpleJbehave\target\jbehave' using formats '[]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
Reports view generated with 0 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 0 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 29264
Only local connections are allowed.
[1578918833.831][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Jan 13, 2020 6:03:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.43*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.43*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- Presumably you are using the updated *chrome= 79.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 79**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *unknown* to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.43* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.

Comment: Hello sir even though I have updated the chrome version, chrome driver and JDK to 8 but still I'm facing the same issue. following error occurred                            Starting  ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}) on port 8182
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1578983646.230][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Jan 14, 2020 12:04:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession.

Comment: @kishankulkarni You are closer now. See the change from `INFO: Detected dialect: OSS` to `INFO: Detected dialect: W3C`. Can you add the current logs within the question?

Comment: Where can I find the logs? I'm bit new to this concept can you please guide me.

Comment: @kishankulkarni The same start-up and error logs `Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210.....`

Comment: Comment line 1 : Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}) on port 8182
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1578983646.230][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Jan 14, 2020 12:04:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C